# this.currentUserSubject.asObservable is not a function

Tags: angular, import, rxjs

I'm using the latest version of Angular and in my researches I understand that every new release causes obvious changes in the imports of libraries. This is the way I was used to code in previous releases of Angular but now, as I build the app I get this error: `this.currentUserSubject.asObservable is not a function`. I looked for similar issues but as I said, the new releases make things work differently and at this point, I'm completely lost...Can someone give me a help? The relevant code

Auth Service TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject , Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../models/User';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {


  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  currentUser: Observable<User>;
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private jwt: JwtHelperService) {
    this.currentUserSubject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));


    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mars-rover",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

And the navbar TS where I need to subscribe the currentUser

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public isMenuCollapsed = true;
  user: User;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
     this.authService.currentUser.subscribe(user=>{
      this.user = user;
      console.log(user)
    })
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize currentUserSubject as a subject instead of a string.

```js
this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
```

Comment: of course...this has nothing to do with releases, the code was wrong...its a stupid post....Thank you for point me out!